# Google Play Services

Tags: google, google-play-services

My phone keeps telling me... "Google Play Services has stopped working"... I don't know what it means but it pops up SO MUCH and it's VERY annoying. I have tried doing a soft reset, but that did not work. I have also shut it down multiple times.

Comment: Have you installed a custom ROM (like CyanogenMod)?

Comment: Starting happening to me a few days ago as well. No custom ROM or any other changes of note.

Answer (score 0):

Open app manager. Go to Google Play Services>Uninstall updates(Clear data/cache)>Disable it. Then re-enable again and update. See if it worked.

Comment: Does not help in my case, because I cannot access the Play store to update due to the same error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Settings>Apps or Applications Manager>All. Select Google Play Services.
2. Go to Storage>Tap on Clear Data> Click OK
3. Do the same thing for Download manager and Google Play Store
4. If it still doesn't work, uninstall updates for Google Play Services and Play Store.
5. If all else fails, do a Factory Data reset